# What Ruby language construct is "respond_to do |x| .. end" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I am new to ruby and rails. Can someone please point out what is the below construct. I see the respond_to constructs in methods (def). So is it a method inside a method ? I mean I am trying to understand the language construct here.

I do understand its functionality, that is send the response in a given format.

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
```

Comment: It (`respond_to`) is a method that is being passed a block (**keyword!**). Also, it should be `end`, not `ends` ..

Comment: so is it like a self executing method ?

Comment: It is up to the method (`respond_to`) to *invoke* the block as desired (with `yield`). `Array.each` will invoke the block once *for each element* (which would be not at all for an empty array ;-), for instance. Blocks are *similar* to anonymous functions, as are commonly used in JavaScript. However, they are *not* first-class values (inside the method the block can be lifted/promoted by `Proc` by using the `&block` syntax).

Comment: Thanks. Can u post is an answer, I will mark it as answered then.

Comment: It really deserves more attention, like a link or two. I'll pass tonight, but it'll get some love :)

Comment: http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language construct is a ruby block. But if you really want to understand `respond_to` here's a blog post that provides a good overview

[How does respond_to work?](http://tokumine.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/how-does-respond_to-work-in-the-rails-controllers/)

> The key thing to understand is that respond_to is a method attached to
> your controllers superclass: ActionController, and we are passing in
> as an argument something called a block:
>
> ...
>
> inside the respond_to method, we end up with a Proc that takes one
> argument. This argument has the .xml and .html methods called on it.
> What do we pass into the Proc as an argument when we call it from
> inside respond_to? We pass in an instance of the Responder class.
>
> So we end up calling .html and .xml on an instance of the responder
> class as it is passed into the block (that’s been converted to a Proc)
> inside the respond_to method… Phew.

Comment: So both html and json methods are called on the instance of the responder (format) class. So does it mean rails will return response for both of these ?

Comment: yes, rails will return json for if you call it with `website/book.js` and html for `website/book.html`.

Answer (score 2):

It's closure. It's like pasing a function to function in other languages, i. e. in Ruby you have two option to iterate over collection:

```
for elem in collection
  # do something
end
```

or

```
collection.each do |elem|
  # do something
end
```

There is a difference between this two but I don't describe it here. So as you can see it's like passing an function to the method and run it inside. But there are also two methods to pass block, using `do |variables| ... end` block or `{ |variables| ... }` block. If you want to write own method that accept blocks there again are more than one way to do it (they are a little different but will run the same way):

```
def run_3_times
  yield
  yield
  yield
end
```

or

```
def run_3_times(&block)
  block.call
  block.call
  block.call
end
```

both of them is called the same way:

```
run_3_times { puts 'hello' }
# will yield
hello
hello
hello
```

but will cause another error when block isn't passed:

```
# when using yield
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)

# when using Proc.call
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
from (pry):8:in `run_3_times'
```

Here you have some articles about it:

- http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html
- http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

Comment: Becouse `for ... in` do not introduce new scope.

Answer (score -1):

On Ruby    **.respond_to?**  is a test method.  One of the things that does is takes a symbol and returns a **true** if the object can receive a method, a **false** if it doesn't.
  For example,:
    **[1, 2, 3].respond_to?(:push)**
would return **true**, since you can call **.push** on an array object.
 However
    **[1, 2, 3].respond_to?(:to_sym)**
would return **false**, since you can't turn an array into a symbol

Links:
 a] Ruby is oriented to what methods call answers to, rather than what type an object is.
[respond_to?](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/ruby-beginner-en-1o8Mb/2/3?curriculum_id=5059f8619189a5000201fbcb)